# JSON response format error - red dot\bullet before response

Tags: json, google-chrome-devtools

I am sending an AJAX request expecting JSON response.
However, the returned JSON is preceded with a red dot\bullet which is causing a parse error.

Here is a screenshot from `Postman`:
[image]

The dot is not shown on `Raw` or `Preview` display, only on `Pretty`.

In Chrome Dev Tools Network tab it appears under `Response`. `Preview` is shown normally as if the dot isn't there.

[image]

[image]

Comment: In Chrome, red dots usually represents non-printable special unicode characterss. Please check your server side code to prevent outputting those characters.

Comment: Why is the "XML" button pressed?

Comment: Doesn't matter. JSON button showing the same

Comment: Well, if the web server sends JSON identified as XML and you're relying on some automated parsing, that might explain the issue as well. Whatever, did you understand devnull69's comment?

Comment: Yes. @devnull69, can you please post your comment as an answer?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As mentioned in a comment before: In Chrome, red dots usually represent non-printable special unicode characters.

Please check your server side code to prevent outputting those characters

Comment: It was probably a file encoding problem caused by editing the files on the remote end with notepad. I've re-uploaded the files from the localhost and it was solved.

Comment: Windows Notepad adds BOM information to UTF-8 files (i.e. FFFE or FEFF at the beginning of the file) which would explain this behavior. In Notepad++ for example you can prevent UTF-8 from including BOM information using the "Format" menu

Comment: For the record: BOM = "Byte Order Marker" (sequence of bytes that allows the reader to identify a file as being encoded in UTF-8).

Answer (score 6):

If your files are encoding with UTF-8, better to encode them with UTF-8 without BOM. This can be easily done through notepad++. The steps are as follows,

1. Open your files in notepad++.
2. Go to Encoding option on the file menu.
3. Then select the option "convert to UTF-8 without BOM".

This may resolve your problem.

Answer (score 3):

You need to clear you object buffer on server side.
I am using PHP as my server side language and I faced similar problem and the solution was cleaning my buffer using `ob_clean();`

Answer (score 3):

I was faced red dots problem in my  ajax response I tried a lot of solution but doest work for me after then I tried ob_clean() function I got the solution
I solved my problem using ob_clean() inside the constructor method

```
function __construct()
{
    ob_clean();
}
```

Comment: explain your answer briefly for other users.

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem and fixed this by converting the file from utf-8 to utf-8 without BOM