# CakePHP AJAX Json Parse Error when using Model

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json, cakephp

I'm developing an application using CakePHP 2.5.3.0, and then I stumbled upon a problem with AJAX:

I'm using an AJAX request from jQuery to CakePHP to send the user's login and password, and then CakePHP should return a JSON response validated. The problem is: Whenever I'm using a Model method within my action method in the Controller, the JSON response comes out with an unexpected character before the start of the JSON.

Here's a screenshot when seeing response on Google Chrome:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/bKx3i.png

The jQuery AJAX Request Code is here:

```
        $.ajax({
            url: "/login/signin.json",
            cache: false,
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            data: {
                email: $("#login-form").find("input[name=email]").val(),
                password: $("#login-form").find("input[name=password]").val()   
            },
            success: function(response) {               
                self.callback.login(response);
            }
        });
```

And here is the LoginController's "signin" method:

```
        public function signin() {
        if(!$this->request->is("ajax"))     
            throw new BadRequestException();

        $this->layout = 'ajax';
        $this->response->disableCache();

        $this->RequestHandler->respondAs("application/json");

        if($this->request->is("post")):             
            $account = $this->Account->validateAccount($this->request->data['email'], Security::hash($this->request->data['password'],"sha1",true));

            if(count($account)>0):
                $account = $account['Account'];
                $message = array(   "success" => true,
                                    "message" => "[]");

                $AccountManager = new AccountSessionManager();
                $AccountManager->setId($account['id_account']);
            else:
                $message = array(   "error" => true,
                                    "message" => "The entered e-mail or password are invalid",
                                    "code" => 2 );
            endif;
        else:
            $message = array(   "error" => true,
                                "message" => "No POST request.",
                                "code" => 1 );
        endif;  

        $this->set("message", $message);
        $this->set("_serialize", array('message'));

        $this->render("ajax");
    }
```

The view file for "ajax" which I rendered above is a simple

```
<?php echo $message ?>
```

---

But then whenever I change this line

```
$account = $this->Account->validateAccount($this->request->data['email'], Security::hash($this->request->data['password'],"sha1",true));
```

to

```
$account = array();
```

I don't get that strange character before the json response.

I have no clue why this happens, but this happens **only** when I use **any** Model methods within the Controller...

By the way, the error I get from javascript is:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token

And the unexpected character I'm talking about is the little red dot in Chrome before the json.

Comment: possible duplicate of [JSON response format error - red dot\bullet before response](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23511275/json-response-format-error-red-dot-bullet-before-response)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That character appears because one of your php files have space on newline before open php tag

just check your models or configs on whatever to find extra newline or space.

Also [BOM character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) can produce such result. PHP files should not have any BOM. If you have used Windows Notepad to edit you files it's BOM for sure. Just use one of editors for programming.

Have you googled before asking? [JSON response format error - red dot\bullet before response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23511275/json-response-format-error-red-dot-bullet-before-response)

Comment: Yea, that really did the trick... That was not the first time I had problems with BOM, though. I use Dreamweaver. The funny part is: I had already set it to NOT USE BOM by default, so I didn't even search about that. And yet it was using BOM... Strange, huh? Anyways, thanks for the fast response :)

Comment: I'm glad that it's fixed your issue.