# Jquery Ajax Parse Error (Red Dot)

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am using jQuery ajax to sent an input value to php function on server side.

I intend to receive json response. My "dataType" is set to json.

But I get a parse error as response. 
Using the Network tab in browser, I see a line-space and a red "dot" breaking the json response (image attached).

Below is how it is:

```
1) 

2) .

3) #correct json response.
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This question is a little short on information. Can you share the code you have tried?

Comment: The image is missing

Comment: Please just add code you tried

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25588082/cakephp-ajax-json-parse-error-when-using-model and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23511275/json-response-format-error-red-dot-bullet-before-response

Comment: Ajax Call
var ajaxurl=  "<?php echo admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ); ?>";
jQuery.ajax({
  type: "POST",
        url: ajaxurl,
        dataType: 'json',
        data: 'action=refering_channel_check&channel='+jQuery(this).val(),
        success: function(data) {
 
        },
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
         alert(xhr + status + error);
         }
    });

});

Comment: PHP Function

function refering_channel_check()
{


    $output="";
    $referring_channel=$_POST['channel'];
    if($referring_channel=="" || empty($referring_channel)){
                $output=array('return'=>'-4','ref_value'=>'');
                echo json_encode($output);
                die();

}

die();
}

Comment: One of the solutions suggested:

"Please check your server side code to prevent outputting those characters"

Which would be this server side code.

The admin-ajax.php (ajax url) is the default unmodified file of wordpress.