# Codeigniter prints a strange character before every output

Tags: php, json, web-services, codeigniter, php-5.6

I made an API in PHP codeigniter framework which returns JSON output. The output appeared fine but I wasn't able to parse it : it always gave a parsing error.

On parsing with online JSON parser, I realised all the API outputs have a weird special character in the beginning, irrespective of whether I return JSON or a simple string. ( **see below** )

[image]

**[this](http://mridulahuja.com/api/index.php/cleaner/getCleaner?mobile=8888888888&pass=bhghg)** is the link to my API and I tested the output on [JSLint](http://jsonlint.com/)

Can you help me figure out where is this character in the beginning coming from ?

This is my controller code :

```
public function getCleaner(){
    $mobile_no = $this->input->get('mobile');
    $pass = $this->input->get('pass');
    if(!is_null($mobile_no) && !is_null($pass))
    {
        header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');  
        header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8');
        header('x-xss-protection: 1;');
        $data = $this->cleaner_model->get_cleaner($mobile_no, $pass);
        if(!empty($data))
            echo json_encode($data);
        else 
            echo '{"cleaner_id":"-10","cleaner_name":"cleaner_not_found"}';
    }
}
```

And this is my model code :

```
public function get_cleaner($mobile, $pass){
     $this->db->select("*");
     $this->db->from("cleaner");
     $this->db->where("mobile1", $mobile);
     $this->db->where("user_pass", $pass);
     $data = $this->db->get()->row_array();

     return $data;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you use to create JSON is not correct. Use following to get correct output (in ELSE block at your controller)

```
//this is WRONG
 echo '{"cleaner_id":"-10","cleaner_name":"cleaner_not_found"}';

//this is correct
$arr = array('cleaner_id' => '-10', 'cleaner_name' => 'cleaner_not_found');
echo json_encode($arr);
```

Now you will receive correct data as

```
{"cleaner_id":"-10","cleaner_name":"cleaner_not_found"}
```

Comment: Thanks . but what about http://mridulahuja.com/api/index.php/cleaner/getCleaner?mobile=8888888888&pass=password  ? Here the output is being generated by json_encode only, but it still prints that character.

Comment: That character appears because one of your php files have space on newline before open php tag

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25588082/cakephp-ajax-json-parse-error-when-using-model

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23511275/json-response-format-error-red-dot-bullet-before-response

Comment: Thanks for putting me on the right track ! The model had the same character ( though not visible ) in the beginning. I removed it and it solved the problem. Thanks again :)

Comment: great. You may accept this answer as your issue fixed. Thanks