# Jquery Autocomplete works on localhost but gives me parseerror on remote server

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

Currently I am working on a website project, and I met a very strange "bug" with jQuery autocomplete and Ajax + PHP.

If I am running script + PHP on my own computer's web server, I get the correct formatted JSON values, and autocomplete works.
When I upload my whole project to a remote server (like another computer on the same network) I always get a JSON ParseError.

Here is my script:

```
    $("#datum_filter").autocomplete({
        minLength: 2,
        source: function(request, response){
            $.ajax({
                url: "autocomplete.php?filter=datum",
                data:{
                    mode : "ajax",
                    limit : 15,
                    term : request.term
                },
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(data){
                    try{
                    } 
                    catch (e){
                        alert(e);
                    }
                    response(data);
                },
                error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                    console.log(errorThrown); console.log(textStatus);
                }
            })
        },
        select:  function(e, ui){
            var val = ui.item.value;
            alert("Clicked item: " + val); 
        }
    }); 
});
```

and PHP:

```
if($_REQUEST["filter"] == "datum"){
    try{       
        $stmt = $DB->prepare('SELECT datum FROM data WHERE datum LIKE :term GROUP BY datum');
        $stmt->execute(array('term' => '%'.$_GET['term'].'%'));

        while($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
        $data[] =  $row['datum'];
        }

    }catch(PDOException $e){
        echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }

    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

Responses from my local and remote server:
Local PC & Server
[image: Local PC & Server]
Remote Server
[image]

Remote server error:

> SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 2 of the JSON data
>   [...]
>   parsererror

Thanks for your help!

Comment: is it a UTF-8 bom? see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23511275/json-response-format-error-red-dot-bullet-before-response

Comment: Every file have UTF-8 encoding without BOM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I managed it to work. I had a file "config.php" (It contains MYSQL PDO config etc. and included it in my main php file.).
I totally forgot it to change encoding to UTF-8 encoding without BOM ( I kept it in simply UTF-8) thats what caused the problem on my remote server.

Thank you guys for your tips, these gave me some useful advice for the future.

Answer (score 0):

Your `autocompletephp` is different on the remote server. One version is returning 33 chars, the other 30 chars. Upload your local version of that file (files) to the remote server.

Comment: I'm using same files on both server.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure perhaps it's a security implementation you could try

```
echo json_encode(array("Results" => $data));
```

This will force your JSON data sent to the browsers to be an Object and not an Array, but this is just a theory as it stand it should be working, the only things i can suggest is set the `Content-type` header to `application/json` it could be a content-type collision and then there is comment provided by @Rick

Comment: I added content type + array, but i get the same error.
New response on remote server: {"Results":["2016-10-01","2016-10-02"]}

Comment: Ok the last thing i can surgest is at the start of your file put `ob_start()` and the end of the file `ob_clean()` then above your `echo` put `ob_start()`, after put `ob_end_flush(); exit(0);`  and see if something else in PHP is outputing before even if it's a space or null char lol

Comment: if not the only think i can ask is if you can give us access to the web site, so i can download the result's file using wget and HEX edit inspect it :)

Comment: I've already tried this, but nothing happened.

I made a test with filewriter. I've written out my $data  to a txt file, and its contents are the same on my local computer and remote server. I'm totally out of idea, what's wrong.